# Option Link and Display Value

Tags: php, html

Alright, so what I have is a standard select option in an HTML form, but what I'm trying to do is display the name and at the same time link to another page, while i'm trying to display the name to another page, the output represent the values in the option, so how do I display the name if I want to?

this is my code:

```
                  <select name="ticket" id="ticket" >
                        <option disabled selected>Please Select</option><?php echo !empty($ticket)?$ticket:'';?>
                        <option value="create_email2.php">Email</option>
                        <option value="sort.php">Orlig</a></option>
                        <option>Task</option>
                        <option>Project</option>
                        <option>Meeting</option>
                        <option>Disscussion</option>
                        <?php if (!empty($ticketError)): ?>
                            <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $ticketError;?></span>
                        <?php endif;?>
```

and this code to call the value:

$ticket = $_POST['ticket'];
echo $ticket;?>

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener on the select which will replace **location.href** with the selected value.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("ticket").addEventListener("change",function(){
    // Get the value of the select
    var value = this.value;

    // Check if the value ends with .php to avoid invalid redirects
    if (/\.php$/.test(value)) {

        // Change the page
        location.href = value;
    }
});
</script>
</body>
```

This is JavaScript, place the code in the **script** tags, including the tags themselves, in your page, right before the closing **body** tag.

Comment: its doesn't seem to work, I try paste on top of the .php but nothing happen

Comment: I try to put it above the end of the body but still nothing change, am Im still doing something wrong?

Comment: heres my completed code for the first page: https://codeshare.io/G6pYKo n this one for the page I want it to display back: https://codeshare.io/2K8PDY